# How to test Reference type value in cdk stack?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am using aws cdk library to create resource and was able to create resources succuessfully. Now want to test this generated statck. Again if its single resources then able to test it fine but when stack has more than one resources then don't how to rest that.

Following is code to create resources.

```
constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: CIAMSQSProps = {} ) {
    super(scope, id);

    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, id, {
      queueName: props.queueName!,
    });
    
    let ssmParamters = new CreateSSMParamaters(this, id, {
      envName: props.envName!,
      envValue: sqsQueue.queueUrl
    });
}
```

Following is the code for testing and it fails because stack contains reference.

```
test('Test SSM Parameter', () => {
  const app = new App();
  const sqsStack = new TestSQS(app, 'test-sqs-stack', {
    queueName: 'TestQueue',
    envName: 'TestQueue',
  });

  const template = Template.fromStack(sqsStack);
  template.hasResourceProperties(ResourceTypes.SSM_PARAM_TYPE, "{ Name: 'TestQueue', Value: 'TestQueue', Type: 'String' }");
});
```

Following is the error.

```
Template has 1 resources with type AWS::SSM::Parameter, but none match as expected.
    The closest result is:
      {
        "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
        "Properties": {
          "Type": "String",
          "Value": {
            "Ref": "testsqsstackEDC1E09E"
          },
          "Name": "TestQueue"
        }
      }
    with the following mismatches:
        Expected type string but received object at /Properties (using objectLike matcher)
```

can someone help me on this? Or is there any way to test specific property for resource type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found several options to test property references.  I have not seen any documented best practice on this topic. Perhaps this is because, in most cases, we need not test such implementation details.

**Option 1:**  Export the source `Construct` from its `Stack`.  [Resolve](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Stack.html#resolveobj) its `Token` value.

```js
template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::SSM::Parameter', {
  Value: stack.resolve(stack.queue.queueName),
});
```

**Option 2:**  As above, but use [escape hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) instead of field export to get the queue reference.

```js
const childQueue = stack.node.tryFindChild('MyQueue') as sqs.Queue;

template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::SSM::Parameter', {
  Value: stack.resolve(childQueue.queueName),
});
```

**Option 3:**  Find the queue resource's name in the template.

```js
const queues = template.findResources('AWS::SQS::Queue');
expect(Object.keys(queues)).toHaveLength(1);
const resolvedQueueName = Object.keys(queues)[0];

template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::SSM::Parameter', {
  Value: { 'Fn::GetAtt': [resolvedQueueName, 'QueueName'],},
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`new Capture()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions-readme.html#capturing-values) can allow you to test a specific property for the resource type, output, mapping (and probably others per AWS docs).

The example below is what I've used to test.

```ts
describe.each(['env1', 'env2'])('The allowed %s Parameter Store resource', env => {
  const nestedStack = createTestStack(env);
  it(`should match the specified name pattern`, () => {
    // given
    const template = Template.fromStack(nestedStack);
    const nameCapture = new Capture();  // one capture per value
    const valueCapture = new Capture(); 

    // when
    template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::SSM::Parameter', {
      Name: nameCapture,
      Value: valueCapture
    });

    // then
    expect(nameCapture.asString()).toEqual(`/${env}/allowed/demo`);
    expect(valueCapture.asString()).toMatch(<regExPatternHere>);
  });
```

Below is your code using `Capture()`

```ts
test('Test SSM Parameter', () => {
      const app = new App();
      const sqsStack = new TestSQS(app, 'test-sqs-stack', {
        queueName: 'TestQueue',
        envName: 'TestQueue',
      });

      const template = Template.fromStack(sqsStack);
      const nameCapture = new Capture;
      const valueCapture = new Capture;
      const typeCapture = new Capture;

      template.hasResourceProperties(ResourceTypes.SSM_PARAM_TYPE,
        "{ 
        Name: nameCapture, 
        Value: valueCapture,
        Type: typeCapture 
        ");

        //run test here on individual values if desired 
      });
```